# C++ Multithread Join

Tags: c++, multithreading

In C++ documents it states that the `join()` function blocks the caller, but I saw a lot of C++ multithreading code examples like below, my question is would that make these three threads actually executed sequentially? If it's true, does it mean if I want my threads to run parallel I should use detach?

```
std::thread t1 (pause_thread,1);
std::thread t2 (pause_thread,2);
std::thread t3 (pause_thread,3);
t1.join();
t2.join();
t3.join();
```

Comment: `join` blocks the calling thread, not any other thread

Comment: If it blocks the caller, after calling "t1.join();" wouldn't the caller thread wait t1 is finished and then call "t2.join();" ? @NathanOliver-IsonStrike

Comment: The constructors start the background threads. it's just that you're waiting for the threads to complete their work in order. The thread logic can still run in parallel. While you're waiting for the first thread to complete, all 3 background threads can still run in parallel...

Comment: Yes, `t2.join()` can't happen until after `t1.join()` completes, but `t2` is still running while that wait happens.  If you need all three threads to finish before you move on this is the way to do it.

Comment: Does that mean the logic of t2 is actually starts after "std::thread t2 (pause_thread,2);" instead of "t2.join()" ? @NathanOliver-IsonStrike

Comment: "would that make these three threads actually executed sequentially?" Nope.  "does it mean if I want my threads to run parallelly I should use detach?" Nope. `join` means "wait until that thread finishes". Waiting for one specific thread to finish doesn't make the other threads stop and wait.

Comment: use `std::jthread` instead of `std::thread`

Comment: @SolomonSlow I made a typo (wrong edit). It was meant to say "in principle you should never call detach". My apologies for any confusion I created, and thank you for the feedback. Corrected version below

Comment: In principle you should never call detach. At the end of your program you should be able to synchronize with all the threads, and if necessary "ask" them to abort their work and finish so that each thread can cleanup resources it is using before terminating

Comment: @RBB Yes.  The thread starts as soon as you create it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```C++
std::thread t1 (pause_thread,1);  // Creates a thread to call pause_thread(1)
std::thread t2 (pause_thread,2);  //    ''   "   ''   ''  ''  pause_thread(2)
std::thread t3 (pause_thread,3);  //    ''   "   ''   ''  ''  pause_thread(3)

// All three threads _potentially_ are running at this point. Though it's
// possible that some of them already could have finished, and it's possible
// that some of them have not yet started.

t1.join();  // Wait for the t1 thread to finish its work.

// Can't get here until the t1 thread has finished. The t2 thread, and the
// t3 thread could be in any state; finished, still running, or not
// even started.
 
t2.join();  // Wait for t2 thread to finish.

// Can't get here until both the t1 and t2 threads have finished. The t3 thread
// still could be in any state...

t3.join();  // Wait for t3 thread to finish.

// Can't get here until all three; t1, t2, and t3 have finished.
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's how it works in real life.

You are the boss. You call your assistant and tell them to prepare the next week's agenda for you. You call your other assistant and tell them to screen CVs of hiring candidates. You call yet another assistant and tell them to prepare a big product presentation due tomorrow. You ask each to message you on Teams when they are done, as they always do when they get an assignment from you.

What you don't tell them is that you want to slack out while they are busy working for you!

Since you are the boss you have all chats on mute so you don't get pop ups or anything when a message arrives. So you open the first assistant's chat on Teams and just wait for their message. (Perhaps it's already there if they are quick!) When it arrives, you open the second assistant's chat on Teams and wait for their message. (It also may or may not be already there). When it arrives, you open the third assistant's chat on Teams and wait for their message. (It may already be there too). When it arrives, you call it a day and go home.

That's exactly the spawn-join protocol.

Absolutely nothing here suggest that your assistant execute their assignments sequentially.

You go home at the moment the slowest assistant finishes their assignment, plus possibly a very brief period of time you need to check messages from other assistants.

The spawn-detach protocol says that you go home without ever checking their messages. But if you go home before they finish, they might see you are no longer there and go home too, without finishing their assignments. So you want to ensure they are all finished by some other means.

(This answer is not sponsored by or affiliated with Microsoft Teams).